# Unsigned Short override

Tags: gcc, unsigned

while (fscanf(fp, "%s", strings[cnt++] ) != EOF);

cnt is an unsigned short. It has 65535. So when ever the file reaches more than those many words, cnt again initialises to 0 and continues. My question is does this happen on all compilers or just gcc?

Answer (score 2):

```
char filename[128];
strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
```

`filename` can only store 128 characters (127 + NULL character). The overflow can occur when the user passes an argument that has more than 127 characters (as pointed by paxdiablo).

Ideally, your application would count how many characters there are in the input parameter and allocate a variable large enough to store this information:

```
int param_size = strlen(argv[1]);
char* filename = malloc(param_size+1);
if (!filename)
{
     // TODO: memory allocation failed! Need to handle error.
     // (notify the user, quit the application or something).
}
strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
```

Comment: More than 127, actually, since it stores the null terminator as well but +1 since the error is a minor one and doesn't really affect the answer.

Comment: One other suggestion, Karl, it's not really necessary to zero the memory since you _know_ you're going to overwrite it all anyway with the `strcpy`. And you probably want to check the return from `malloc` but I think I've been way too nitpicky today :-)

Comment: I understand, thanks. One other thing that memset() does is set the NULL character at the end as well. I think I'll simplify this task, come back in a few minutes.

Comment: `strcpy` puts the null at the end as well, but I'll wait :-)

Comment: How is it possible that you don't have a twitter account? There are **cmd-line Twitter clients** for Linux, you know :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different vulnearabilities here:

1. `strcpy(filename, argv[1]);`, which others have mentioned.
2. `strings[cnt++]` - if the file contains more than `USHRT_MAX` lines, you'll exceed the `strings` array. You'll start reading into stack areas used for other things.
3. `fscanf(fscanf(fp, "%s",...` - if a line contains more than 79 characters, you'll overwrite the following line. It will be harmless, unless you exceed the entire strings array.

Comment: 80 characters should be 79. This is probably an unintentional bug, someone likely forgot space for the null termination.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin, indeed 80 chars are enough for overflow. Fixed answer. I wouldn't say someone forgot the null termination - more like someone forgot that buffer sizes are important. Files can easily exceed 80 characters per line (unless they're read from punched cards).

Answer (score 0):

Vulnerabilities:

1) There is no check of argc to see if there actually exists an argv[1]. The index might be invalid, if the user just typed homework.exe without any command line parameters.

2) There is no check of whether the contents of argv[1] will fit in the filename buffer. Right now, it assumes that the file is built of text lines, where no line is longer than 79 characters.

3) A certain file format is assumed by fscanf(). This may or may not be a vulnerability. If it doesn't contain strings in a given format, or if it contains more lines than what will fit inside an unsigned short, the program will crash & burn.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably avoid code like this:

```
char filename[128];
strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
```

...and write code more like this:

```
#define BUFSIZE 128
char filename[BUFSIZE];
strncpy(filename, argv[1], BUFSIZE);
```

The strNcpy version of strcpy limit the characters you can copy. using macros for sizes is good, so you can change these buffer size later, and you don't fill your code with magical numbers.

For the same reason, you sould avoid using fscanf directly, you can use a function to pass a fixed size string, not a unbounded one. or you can do something like this

```
strings[STRINGSIZE] = 0; 
cnt = cnt %  STRINGSIZE;
```

...so you warantee that your string has a size limit inside the limits.